# How can I turn off QSA? (query string append)

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, query-string

I'm using Apache2 and mod_rewrite to hide my query strings. These are the rules in question.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}                 ^query=(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*)                            /search/%1             [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^search\/?$                     /search/?query=test    [R=301,L]
```

When I visit `/search` (or `/search/`) I am correctly redirected to `/search/?query=test` (as per the last rule)

From there, the `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` should kick in and redirect me to `/search/test`, right? From what I understand the `%1` in my first `RewriteRule` corresponds to the `(.*)` in the `RewriteCond` which should contain `test`.

However, what actually happens is I'm redirected to `/search/test/?query=test`. So, the rule works, but for some reason the query string appended. **Is it the QSA option being automatically added somehow/somewhere?**

I'm then stuck in an infinite loop of redirecting to `/search/test?query=test` because the first `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` kick in again, and again, and again...

What am I doing wrong?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to specify an [empty query in the substitution](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) to prevent the original requested query to be appended to the new URL:

> **Modifying the Query String**
>
> By default, the query string is passed through unchanged. You can, however, create URLs in the substitution string containing a query string part. Simply use a question mark inside the substitution string to indicate that the following text should be re-injected into the query string. When you want to erase an existing query string, end the substitution string with just a question mark. To combine new and old query strings, use the [QSA] flag.

So:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^query=(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /search/%1? [R=301,L]
```