# htaccess redirect files to new domain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to direct all files on one domain to the homepage of the new domain (I have to due to a new structure). I seem unable to do this, so for example I use the below code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^olddomain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.co.uk [R=301,L]
```

But if I have the below link:

www.olddomain.co.uk/shop/product_info.php?cPath=592&products_id=9335 it does not direct as I want it to, I want it to direct to the homepage of www.newdomain.co.uk but it goes to:

http://www.newdomain.co.uk/?cPath=592&products_id=9335

What do I need to do to amend the htacess on the old domain?

Thanks

Comment: Check [webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/). You'll probably get a better answer there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop htaccess rewrite rule carrying over query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122530/how-to-stop-htaccess-rewrite-rule-carrying-over-query-string)

Comment: Perhaps this one is more informative: [How can I turn off QSA? (query string append)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986868/how-can-i-turn-off-qsa-query-string-append)

Comment: I added this onto the end...

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cpath=(.*)$
    RewriteRule (.*) / [R=301,L]

But still cannot get it working.

Comment: From the duplicate: `Just add ? at the end of rewritten URL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cpath= [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /? [R=301,L]
```

`/?` in target will strip off original query string.